# Compile error when use talloc

Tags: c, memory, compiler-errors

I write the code below to test the talloc:

```
#include "talloc.h"

typedef struct linklist
{
    char* str;
    struct linklist* next;
}LinkList;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    LinkList* lptr=talloc(NULL,LinkList);
    lptr->str=talloc_strdup(lptr,"Test ptr");

    talloc_free(lptr);

    return 0;
}
```

But got **compile error**:

```
talloctest.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `talloc_named_const(void const*, unsigned int, char const*)'
talloctest.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `talloc_strdup(void const*, char const*)'
talloctest.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `talloc_free(void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I find the definition of relative macros and functions:
Definition in "talloc.h":

```
#define talloc(ctx, type) (type *)talloc_named_const(ctx, sizeof(type), #type)
char *talloc_strdup(const void *t, const char *p);
```

Implemetation in "talloc.c":

```
void *talloc_named_const(const void *context, size_t size, const char *name)
{
    return _talloc_named_const(context, size, name);
}

char *talloc_strdup(const void *t, const char *p)
{
    if (unlikely(!p)) return NULL;
    return __talloc_strlendup(t, p, strlen(p));
}
```

Can someone tell me why?I have tried both talloc-1.3.0 and talloc-2.0.7,but got the same result.

Comment: **Show compiler invocation.**

Comment: Please explain in detail,I just can't understand.

Comment: @chm How are you compiling your code? If it is from the command line, please post the full command you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using talloc as a separate library or compiling it into your executable?  If you're using it as a separate library, you'll need to link to it - at a guess by adding `-ltalloc` to your build command.

Comment: I am just compiling it into my program.

Comment: Can you post the command you use to compile + link your code please? I suspect you might be including the header for talloc in your project but are not compiling its source code yourself. In that case, you'd need to link to a separate talloc library.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.I am using vim,and bind the key 'F5' with command 'gcc -g % -o ./app'.Then the  problem occurred.

Comment: Sorry for replying late.I solved it by compile and link talloc into my         code.